# Line Graph From SharePoint List

Tags: reporting-services

Below table data is stored in SharePoint list(one list)

```
Start year   Complete Year  Column3
2010          2012  
2011          2011  
2011          2014  
2011          2016  
2011          blank
```

Condition
Start year <=2011 and complete year >= 2011 or blank
blank --- we can consider it as today’s date

On Line graph I want to populate below values.

I need count of records(rows) for (for the "start year" 2010, 2011..) on Y-axis and
Start year or years (2010, 2011,2012…) on X-axis

I used a VB code to remove duplicates(2010,2011,2012…) and assigned to SSRS Report Parameter (now parameter has distinct values like 2010,2011,2012…)